# Sum multiple rows of dictionaries in a dataframe, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I add the values and keys of multiple dictionaries based on having the same isolate name?

Example dataframe:

| Isolate | dictionary |
| --- | --- |
| VM20030364 | {'L': 200, 'V': 500, 'T': 300, 'A': 400, 'S': 1} |
| VM20030364 | {'L': 200, 'V': 600, 'T': 300, 'A': 450} |
| VM20030364 | {'L': 100, 'V': 400, 'T': 300, 'A': 400, 'S': 1} |
| UNKNOWN-UW-1773 | {'L': 500, 'V': 360, 'T': 340, 'A': 300, 'S': 1} |
| UNKNOWN-UW-1773 | {'L': 500, 'V': 340, 'T': 340, 'A': 300, 'S': 2} |
| UNKNOWN-UW-1773 | {'L': 500, 'V': 200, 'T': 350, 'A': 310} |

Output dataframe:

| Isolate | dictionary |
| --- | --- |
| VM20030364 | {'L': 500, 'V': 1500, 'T': 900, 'A': 1250, 'S': 2} |
| UNKNOWN-UW-1773 | {'L': 1500, 'V': 800, 'T': 1030, 'A': 910, 'S': 3} |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us map the dictionary column using `Counter`, then `group` the dataframe by `Isolate` and aggregate using `sum`

```
from collections import Counter

df['dictionary'].map(Counter).groupby(df['Isolate']).sum().reset_index()
```

---

```
           Isolate                                          dictionary
0  UNKNOWN-UW-1773  {'L': 1500, 'V': 900, 'T': 1030, 'A': 910, 'S': 3}
1       VM20030364  {'L': 500, 'V': 1500, 'T': 900, 'A': 1250, 'S': 2}
```